# Questions about R survey package

Tags: r, sampling, chi-squared-test, survey

I have to use the R "survey" package and want to be sure to understand it.

I simulated data where the sample comes from a simple random sampling process.
When I compare the result of the Pearson's chi-square test (chisq.test), and the results using svychisq, the p values slightly differ (though really very close), while I expected them to be the same. Am I missing something?

Besides, I want to compare some characteristics between two groups, from data coming from a sampling, with different sampling probabilities but the same probability inside each group (a control group where the sampling probability is 1/1000 for all controls, and an "exhaustive" case group : probability=1 for all cases). In that case, is there a real impact on the test, that justifies using the Rao-Scott chi-square test?

Comment: Interesting. I just posted this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464720/stratified-survey-calculations-by-hand-and-with-survey-package-dont-agree-simu

Answer (score 5):

You would expect slight differences.  The Rao-Scott tests were developed (according to Alastair Scott) to give approximately correct inference for estimated **population** tables, so the code estimates the population table, calls `chisq.test()` on it, and rescales the statistic. Even for simple random sampling, this will introduce slight variations.

When comparing proportions in the two strata under case-control sampling there is no need to use the Rao-Scott test.  The test is for the 2-way association parameter in a loglinear model, and this association parameter is preserved by case-control sampling (for the same reason that logistic regression coefficients are).

[I don't think this has anything to do with the linked [Stratified survey calculations by hand and with survey package don't agree. Simulation results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464720/stratified-survey-calculations-by-hand-and-with-survey-package-dont-agree-simu])